# No identifier/primary key specified for Entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Why do I get this exception

> Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException: No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "Entities\Category" sub class of "". Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key. in /Users/munnik/Sites/doctrine/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php on line 38

for this class:

```
<?php

namespace Entities;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="category") 
  **/   
class Category  {

    /** @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer") @ORM\GeneratedValue **/
    private $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string") **/
    private $name;

}
```

I just can't seem to find the issue? The @ORM\Id should mark $id as primary key?

Comment: You shouldn't need the `name="id"` since the @ORM/Id already defines that. Additionally, put the descriptors into `/** */` code blocks, note only the single asterisk in the ending block. More examples here: [link](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html)